# How to get elements from multidimensional arrar in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I filled my array with buttons (with document.create("input")). I want to print them to screen but I could not get the element mainArr[i][j]. When I console.log() it, print undefined but outside of the scope it gives what I expected. I have tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mainArr.length; i++) {

                var p = document.createElement('P');

                for (var j = 0; j < mainArr[i].length; j++) { 

                    element = mainArr[i][j];

                    p.appendChild(element);
                }
                $('#keyPad').append(p);
            }
```

I expect this output:

```
<p>
                <input type="button" class="sil" value="C" style="width:50px">
                <input type="button" class="hepsiniSil" value="AC" style="width:50px">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="7">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="8">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="9">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="*" >
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="4">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="5">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="6">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="-">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="1">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="2">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="3">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="+">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="0">
                <input type="button" value="=" style="width:50px" onclick='esittir()'>
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="/">

            </p>
```

On the below there is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var butArr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '+', '-', '*', '/', '=', 'C', "AC"];
        var mainArr = [];           


            $('.createBut').click(function () {

                var but = document.createElement("input");

                var butClass = $('#inputClass').val();
                var butValue = $('#inputValue').val();
                var butRow = $('#inputRow').val();
                var butColumn = $('#inputColumn').val();
                var butWidth = $('#inputWidth').val();
                var butHeigth = $('#inputHeigth').val();
                var butClick = $('#inputClick').val();

                but.type = 'button';
                but.value = butValue;
                but.className = butClass;
                but.style.width = butWidth;
                but.style.height = butHeigth;
                //but.onclick = butClick;

                for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
                    mainArr[butRow] = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < 17; j++) {
                        mainArr[butRow][butColumn] = but;

                    }
                }

});
```

Comment: Please share your `mainArr` content

Comment: I shared @CommercialSuicide

Comment: You are not filling your 2D buttons array properly. Plus you have to create a separate button element for each array cell otherwise you will be appending the same button multiple times which will result only one button under the parent it's appended last.

Answer (score 0):

you have mistake in your code - you use:

```
mainArr[butRow][butColumn] = but;
```

where `butRow` and `butColumn` doesn't change

this should fix your problem:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    mainArr[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 17; j++) {
        var but = document.createElement("input");
        but.type = 'button';
        but.value = butValue;
        but.className = butClass;
        but.style.width = butWidth;
        but.style.height = butHeigth;
        mainArr[i][j] = but;
    }
}
```

Comment: But, I take the row and column from the user and should put the button to that indexes. I mean I don't fill the array in order. I fill it according to indexes which user gives me

Comment: so why do you need the loop? it basically does the same thing 17*17 times

Comment: For example user wants to "3" button on the row=1 column=2, to do this I think I need loop for 17 times which is number of buttons.

Comment: That part runs properly, what I ask about first part. Where I try to append P elements

Comment: `console.log(mainArr[0][0]);`
`console.log(mainArr[0][1]);`
`console.log(mainArr[1][0]);`

I did these and first gives undefined others is fine

Comment: `mainArr[butRow] = [];
mainArr[butRow][butColumn] = but;`

Okay, I change that part but still `console.log(mainArr[0][0]);` is undefined